# How do I center the icon properly with background color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

How do I make sure the icon is centered? I do not get why this is happening.

Tried things like:

```
alignment: Alignment.center
```

And:

```
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

And:

```
shrinkWrap: true,
```

Here is the full code:

```
                child:     Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 15),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        MyIcons.icons,
                        size: 24,
                      ),
                    ),

                    Text("Menu item 1")
                  ],
                ),
```

[image: Menu item]

Nothing seems to work. Can you help?

Comment: have you tried by reducing icon size?

Comment: your code is correct work `Icon( Icons.home, ),`

Comment: remove margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 15), cause 25 left

Comment: None of them work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be coming from custom Icon, change it to

```
     Icon(
          Icons.home,
          size: 24,
        ),
```